# Ordination of vowels of a sentence in descending order

Tags: java

Suppose I enter the following string:

```
" Hello party"
```

How could you order only the vowels of that chain, but in a descending way?

to example:

```
"Halle porty"
```

In the following way I have tried to solve the problem, but when I run it tells me that I have an ExeptionBounce 5. How could I correct it? I am also told that the responsible line is the following:

```
if(cad[i].equalsIgnoreCase(vocal[j])

       private String[]cad;
       private String[]vocal={"a","e","i","o","u"};
       private String resp="";   
      private String aux="":
      private String []sort;
      private int cont=0;


    public String ordenar(String cadena)
    {
     cad= cadena.split("");

     for(int i=0; i<cad.legth; i++)
     {

       for(int j=i, j<vocal.legth; j++)
         {

            if(cad[i].equalsIgnoreCase(vocal[j])
             {

            aux+=cad[i];
            sort= aux.Split("");
            Arrays.sort(sort);


           for(int i=0; i<cad.legth; i++)
           {

             cad[i] = sort[k];
             resp+=cad[i];

           }
           }
          }



       return resp;
        }
```

Comment: I don't get the requirement. How do you get "halo mondu" from "Hello World"?

Comment: `j` starts each loop at `i`. `i` must be (in this case) less than 11, `j` must be less than 5. Therefore `i` can be (for example) 8 and must be less than 5. You need to rethink your loop guards.

Comment: Define 'ordination'. Do you mean 'sort'?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not even compile - how are you running it ?

To answer your question, here is a piece of code which given a string will return the string with the vowels sorted:

```
    public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) != -1;
    }
    public static String sortVowelsOnly(String input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return input;
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input);

        //keep track at all positions where we saw a vowel
        ArrayList<Integer> vowelPositions = new ArrayList<>();
        //keep track of all vowels we saw so far
        ArrayList<Character> vowels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int charPosition = 0; charPosition < input.length(); charPosition++) {
            char currentChar = input.charAt(charPosition);
            if(isVowel(currentChar)) {
                vowelPositions.add(charPosition);
                vowels.add(currentChar);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(vowels);

        //now just iterate over all positions where we saw a vowel, and populate it with the vowels from the sorted list
        for(Integer vowelPosition : vowelPositions) {
            char vowel = vowels.remove(0);
            result.setCharAt(vowelPosition, vowel);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```